# Real time server notifications not working properly between RevenueCat and Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-cloud-pubsub, revenuecat

Following those two documentation https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials and https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/google-server-notifications I was trying to set up the Pub/Sub Topic connection on the Dev and QA environments of our app. Using an app admin account with all the privileges I went through all the steps for creating the RevenueCat Credentials JSON, waited for its approval and successfully uploaded it to RevenueCat. When it comes to the second part(enabling real time server notifications) when I try to send the "Test Notification" from the "Monetisation Setup" after putting everything in place the "Test notification couldn't be sent" message pops-up. I went through the flow multiple times but with the same outcome. I am missing something? Is there any extra piece of information that I need to take in consideration besides the two links that I've attached earlier? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1JYx.png)

I've tried following the documentation provided by RevenueCat for setting up the "Real time server notification" of my app in the dev and test enviroments. On production everything is in place.